# How to avoid the use of Subjects in RX

Tags: c#, system.reactive, subject

So I keep reading everywhere that use of `Subject<T>` is "bad" - and I kind of agree with the reasoning.

However, I am trying to think of the best way to avoid using it and have an example.

Currently I have an abstract class for my persisted configuration classes that has a protected `Save()` method on it which is called whenever changing a property should persist the class. This message pumps a message onto a `Subject<T>` which is exposed through `IObservable<T>` interface which the serialisation services listens to and serialises the class. This seemed the most obvious, simple and quickest way to implement this at the time.

So what would be the RX way to do this without using a Subject? Would I instead expose an event and use `Observable.FromEventPattern()` to subscribe to it? - as this seems a more complex way to go about it.

Comment: As a matter of interest, can you link to some of those arguments? I don't think I know enough Rx to answer the question, but this is the first I've heard that you should try to avoid using `Subject`.

Comment: @shambulator Check this link for a quick explanation: http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/18_UsageGuidelines.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not so much that the use of `Subject<T>` is bad - there has to be some way of "entering the monad" - that's the academic way of saying *"get an `IObservable<T>`"*. You need to start somewhere.

The problem with `Subject<T>` arises more when it's used from a subscription instead of chaining existing observables together. Subjects should just exist at the edges of your Rx machinery.

If none of the provided entry points (e.g. `FromEvent`, `FromEventPattern`, `FromAsync`, `Return`, `ToObservable()` and so on) work for you then using `Subject<T>` is perfectly valid. And there's no need to add extra complexity just to facilitate using one of the above - most of them use subjects or subject-like constructs under the covers anyway.

In your case, sounds like `Subject<T>` is just fine. You might what to look at exposing it via [`AsObservable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211761%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in order to hide the implementation details.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to enter the observable is via an Action

```
private Action<ObservableArgs> _action;
```

Create the observable

```
public IObservable<ObservableArgs> GetObservable()
{
    return Observable.FromEvent<ObservableArgs>>(
                ev => _action += ev, 
                ev => _action -= ev);
}
```

Then add to the observable using

```
public void OnNext(ObservableArgs args)
{
    _action?.Invoke(args);
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for providing a direct answer to the question, and for showing why you *shouldn't* avoid the use of `Subject`s. Because otherwise you end up with needlessly complex code, that confuses everyone about its intention, probably including the author themself a couple of months later.